# Enable Youtube in Joomla TinyMCE

Tags: iframe, joomla, tinymce

I can't enable youtube video's in the tinyMCE editor in Joomla 3.4.4 i have changed the settings in the plugin to allow iframe but it still strips the youtube Iframe.

Any thoughts?

Kind regards,

Meton

Answer (score 0):

Try JCE Editor instead. It is a much better editor. Note that you should also modify JCE's settings to allow iframes and JavaScript.